# Replacing string in a .txt file

Tags: c#, io

So my goal is to write a C# program that will read a .txt file with thousands of rows and reformat certain rows with condition.

I will read each row and check if this row contains `1901`, if it does, I want to make changes to the row.

For example this line,

```
 T1.hello < 1901, AS bye
```

I want to replace it with this,

```
 T2.hello AS bye
```

In this case, `hello` and `bye` are the two pieces of data i am going to keep and transit format from `T1.data1 < 1901, AS data2` to `T2.data1 AS data2` if and only if the old row contains `1901`.

Please note `data1` and `data2`  can be any data, they are not always `hello` and `bye`

I have never used IO in C# so I am running out of ideas, so far the code I have is as follows, I am stuck at the `if` statement of my code, I need some guidance on how to handle such situation:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\jzhu\Desktop\test1.txt";
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path));
string fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(path));
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
     if(lines[i].Contains("1901"))
     {         
         //here is the part I need guidance
     }
}
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Create(path));
writer.Write(fileContent);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: Why are you reading the contents of the file twice?

Comment: Is the `T1` part variable or does it always have the literal value of `T1`.  And do you always need to change to `T2`, or is do you need to change Tx => T(x+1), i.e. bump of the value of x?

Comment: @DWright `T1` and `T2` are fixed value, never going to change

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is have

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    if(lines[i].Contains("1901"))
    {         
         sb.AppendLine(lines[i].Replace("< 1901,",""));
    }
    else
    {
        sb.AppendLine(lines[i]);
    }
}

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    writer.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

This will assume that you know that you want to replace "< 1901," with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a case for a regular expression, because you want to capture a variable amount of data after the T1 and preserve it.  Try something like this:

```
string pattern = "T1.([^ ]+) < 1901,( .*)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    Match m = rgx.Match(lines[i]);
    if (m.Success == true) {
        lines[i] = rgx.Replace(lines[i],"T2." + m.Groups[1] + m.Groups[2]);
    }
}
```

The stuff in `()`s in the pattern is the stuff that will get captured, into groups on the `Match` object (the first group on the match--index 0--is the whole matched line itself).

So `([^ ]+)` find everything after 'T1' that is not a space until a space is encountered and stuffs that into `Match` group 2 (index 1).

`( .*)` finds everthing after '1901,', beginning with a space, followed by anything repeated any amount of times `.*`, and stuffs that into group 3 (index 2).  Since these items are preserved in groups, you can now retrieve them when you write the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex.Replace

```
string path = @"C:\Users\jzhu\Desktop\test1.txt";
List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(path));
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
     lines[i] = Regex.Replace(lines[i], @"T1\.([^ ]*) < 1901, AS", "T2.$1 AS");
}
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Comment: but the problem is `data1` and `data2` can be anything, not always `hello` and `bye`

Comment: (that last line should be File.WriteAllLines)

Comment: @HashMap then you can use a regex (edited my code). Thanks, RogerN, I switched to WriteAll.